# Display Execution of Boot Script

Tags: 12.10, boot

I have on the order of 1000 experiments I'd like to run on a modified version of the 3.10 kernel (with Ubuntu 12.10). After every experiment, the machine needs to be rebooted. I've written a Ruby script to do this.

I made the script a boot script (in /etc/init.d) so that the user does not need to login or authenticate as root and the script can run without intervention.

Is there a way to display the output of a boot script while it is executing? I'd like to be able to monitor the status of the experiments or give instructions to the user (press any key to stop, etc). I'm imagining something like a terminal in place of the Ubuntu boot screen with the five little lights, but I'm not really sure what's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing /etc/default/grub to remove "quiet splash" from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. Run "sudo update-grub" to apply the changes.

In the boot command line, "splash" says to cover the screen with the Ubuntu boot logo.

"quiet" says to hide to output of boot scripts.

It sounds like you don't want either.

edit: I forgot about plymouth, another pretty piece of technology that replaces information with branding. If you're still seeing boot logos after removing "splash", put "noplymouth" where "splash" was.

Comment: Works perfectly with "quiet splash" out and "noplymouth" in. Thank you!